# Solving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ without L'Hôpital's Rule.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to solve this limit without the use of L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Well...what's $e^x$?  If it is defined to be $\sum \frac {x^n}{n!}$ then you can use that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Are allowed to use taylor's expansion?

Comment: I don't find the answers in the link all that great. The highest ranked answer doesn't even show the limits exist! If one allows the FTC, then simpler answers can be given.

Answer (score 2):

I would Taylor Expand 
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
and plug in to find
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{24}x^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Well yeah, but L'Hopital is just using taylor expansions in disguise.

Comment: @AliceRyhl. Not in general. ...l'Hopital's rule for finding $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ does not require $f'$' or $g''$ to exist, and even if $f$ or $g$ is infinitely differentiable they may not be analytic.